# for loop only changes first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

i am trying to get my for loop to change all the choices but so they match up for some reason only the first one works

```
<form>
    <div id=q uestion>
        <ul class="question-list">

            <LH id=que>gfh</LH>

            <li id="choice-0">
                <input type="radio" name="radio" id="choice" data-price="100" value="product1" checked="checked">
                <label for="choice1"><span>question 1</span></label>
            </li>

            <li "choice-1">
                <input type="radio" name="radio" id="choice" data-price="110" value="choice2">
                <label for="choice2"><span>question 2 </span></label>
            </li>

            <li "choice-2">
                <input type="radio" name="radio" id="choice" data-price="110" value="product3">
                <label for="product3"><span>question 3 </span></label>
            </li>

            <li "choice-3">
                <input type="radio" name="radio" id="choice" data-price="110" value="product3">
                <label for="product3"><span>question 4 </span></label>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <input type="button" id="jqtest" value="next" onclick=n extQuestion_onclick>
    </div>
</form>
```

here are the choices

```
var allQuestions = [{question: "Who is Prime Minister of the United Kingdom?", choices: ["David Cameron", "Gordon Brown", "Winston Churchill", "Tony Blair"], correctAnswer:0}];
```

here is the function that doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var currentChoise;
    var changeChoice;
    for (currentChoise = 0; currentChoise < allQuestions[0].choices.length; currentChoise++) {

        $('#que').text(allQuestions[0].question);
        $('#choice-' + currentChoise + ' span').text(allQuestions[0].choices[currentChoise]);
    };
});
```

here is js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4ee1552c/

Comment: there are 4 by `id="choice"`, your code looks for choice0, choice1 ... etc. id must be unique in HTML document. your label `for` attributes are wrong too ... and so many other issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of things here:

- you have repeating id's on your inputs. **ID's are always unique**. No discussion on that.
- You are missing the `id=""` attribute on all `li`'s except the first.
- `<label for="">` works for the unique `id=""` attribute, not the inputs `value=""`

You want something like:

```
 <input type="radio" name="product3" id="product3" data-price="110" value="Tony Blair" />
 <label for="product3">question 3</label>
```

check the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ee1552c/2/).

Comment: No! label for works with id attribute not name attribute!

Comment: Your fiddle isn't working when clicking on label. You can see that. Please edit your answer.

Comment: @ebilgin sorry for that premature edit. will update the fiddle

Answer (score 2):

Notice something odd here:

```
<li "choice-1">
```

You missed putting `id`.